# Apache Ignite, C#: Distributed Computing - Topology projection error

Tags: c#, distributed-computing, ignite

I am trying to emulate the Distributed Computing examples in the Apache doc, specifically the [Broadcasting example](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-computing/distributed-computing#broadcasting-a-task).

I start the cluster remotely, where 2 nodes make up the cluster with the following XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>[remoteHost]:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>[localHost1]:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then, I start a node locally with an IP address of [localHost1]:

```
class PrintNodeIdAction : IComputeAction
    {
        public void Invoke()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello node: " +
                              Ignition.GetIgnite().GetCluster().GetLocalNode().Id);
        }
    }
            
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
                {
                    DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                    {
                        IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
                        {
                            Endpoints = new[] { "[remoteHost]", "[remoteHost]:47500..47509" }
                        }
                    }
                };
    
                using (IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
                {
                    // Limit broadcast to remote nodes only.
                    var compute = ignite.GetCluster().ForRemotes().GetCompute();
                    
                    // Print out hello message on remote nodes in the cluster group.
                    compute.Broadcast(new PrintNodeIdAction());
                }
            }
```

However, I run into the following two (2) errors after starting the local node:

```
**1 of 2**
ClusterGroupEmptyException: Topology projection is empty.

**2 of 2**
JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterGroupEmptyCheckedException: Topology projection is empty.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.getTaskTopology(GridTaskWorker.java:688)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:503)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:830)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:498)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:466)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.executeAsync0(IgniteComputeImpl.java:564)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformCompute.executeNative0(PlatformCompute.java:329)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformCompute.processClosures(PlatformCompute.java:294)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformCompute.processInStreamOutObject(PlatformCompute.java:140)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutObject(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:79)
```

Comment: There is only 1 node in the cluster, `ForRemotes()` returns an empty set. Looks like local node can't connect to remote nodes - due to misconfiguration or a firewall.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn So in the remote computer console, I see that the baseline topology changes from 1 to 2 after I run the C# program - so I'm just a bit confused about why the set is empty

Comment: @Mangled_Aura_Nada is it the same question? http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Apache-Ignite-C-NET-Asynchronous-Execution-example-failing-facing-different-errors-td34798.html